# Misleading link about MathJax help

Tags: bug, math-display

The online help of Cross Validated contains the following part at the [LaTeX section](https://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex): "Learn more: [MathJax help](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/)."

Problem is, the link leads to a site about TeX, *not* MathJax. This is not really fortunate, as they're not equivalent; a link like [this](https://github.com/mathjax/) or [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) would have been much more helpful here. (The reason why I used the word "misleading" is that it literally says "MathJax" help, yet the link leads to a TeX site.)

Comment: Good catch. We could probably improve things by adding a link to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Sycorax That's just my second link under the "this" text :)

Comment: Great suggestion.

Comment: Should read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246184/the-mathjax-help-link-should-point-to-a-more-specific-guide/288209#288209

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks! I didn't know; it seems I'm not the first to mention this issue...

Comment: Note for future readers, it now links to `https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/` since the original link no longer exists.